# Adding Favicon to NextJs App router application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js13

I have an issue with the new Next.js [App Router](https://nextjs.org/docs/app). They removed head.js files and now (as it is written in the doc) I have to use [metadata](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/metadata) in layout.ts. My favicon name is `favicon.png`.

How do i specify it here:

```
export const metadata = {
  title: 'Create Next App',
  description: 'Generated by create next app',
}
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can do it as follow:

```
export const metadata = {
  icons: {
    icon: '/icon.png',
  },
};
```

The output will be

```
<link rel="icon" href="/icon.png" />
```

See all documentation regarding icons metadata:

https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/metadata#icons

Comment: You'll also need to add icon.jpg to /public.

Comment: I want sizes too..... something like this `<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.svg" sizes="64x64">` how can i achieve this?

Comment: @UNRIVALLEDKING check out my answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/76059232/9608615) and see if it helps

Comment: important to note that the name of the favicon has to be "icon"

Answer (score 57):

This is the simplest way to use Favicon
in the Next.js 13.4 Stable version.

1. You need to convert your jpg, png, or SVG to .ico. It takes only a few seconds.
2. Rename your .ico file to icon.ico and paste it into the app folder and remove the favicon.ico from the app folder

Done

Comment: I really appreciate your solution - it's the only one that worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you. Can't believe I have to come here to make that clear. Anyone else having troubles with Next 13 App Router docs?

Comment: My `favicon.ico` file was 16 KB and `logo.svg` was 5 KB. So, I put `logo.svg` in `/app` and renamed it to `icon.svg`. This means, you can add png, jpg images too. Just make sure the name starts with `icon`.

Comment: In official doc: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/app-icons it says place `favicon.ico` in `app` folder, why does it not work and we have to use `icon.ico` instead?

Answer (score 13):

To add **multiple icons** and add **other attributes** like `type` and `sizes`:

```js
// layout.tsx
    
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  ...,
  icons: [
    {
      rel: 'icon',
      type: 'image/png',
      sizes: '32x32',
      url: '/favicon/favicon-32x32.png',
    },
    {
      rel: 'icon',
      type: 'image/png',
      sizes: '16x16',
      url: '/favicon/favicon-16x16.png',
    },
    {
      rel: 'apple-touch-icon',
      sizes: '180x180',
      url: '/favicon/apple-touch-icon.png',
    },
  ],
}
```

Comment: thanks it does add sizes attribute but it sets all rel to icons like here is my code
```icons: [
{rel: "icon",type: "image/png",sizes: "32x32",url: "/favicon.png",},
{rel: "apple-touch-icon",type: "image/png",sizes: "180x180",url: "/favicon.png",},
{rel: "shortcut icon",type: "image/png",url: "/favicon.png",},],```

and here is what i got in chrome
 ```<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png" type="image/png" sizes="32x32"><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png" type="image/png" sizes="180x180"><link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png" type="image/png">```

Comment: how would you handle for toggling browser theme from light to dark?

Answer (score 5):

Based on [docs here](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/app-icons#favicon), adding `link` in `RootLayout` will also work

```
export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" sizes="any" />
        {children}
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
// app/layout.tsx

import { Metadata } from 'next';

export const metadata: Metadata = {
  icons: {
    icon: ['/favicon.ico?v=4'],
    apple: ['/apple-touch-icon.png?v=4'],
    shortcut: ['/apple-touch-icon.png'],
  },
  manifest: '/site.webmanifest',
};

// public/
//    |- ...
//    |- android-chrome-192x192.png
//    |- android-chrome-512x512.png
//    |- apple-touch-icon.png
//    |- favicon-16x16.png
//    |- favicon-32x32.png
//    |- favicon.ico
//    |- site.webmanifest
//    |- ...
```

**Icon Convertor:** https://favicon.io/favicon-converter/

Comment: this what i want 

Answer (score 4):

acctually this will be correct,

```
    export const metadata = {
        icons: {
            icon:'/_next/static/media/metadata/favicon.png',
        },
    };
```

and then put you favicon image in that URL (_next/static/media/metadata).

Answer (score 2):

As others have explained, move the `favicon.ico` file from the `public/` directory into the `src/app/` directory. NextJS will then automatically generate the `link` tag in the page's `head` tag ([see here for official docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/app-icons#favicon)).

There is no need to add it to the `metadata` object in `src/app/layout.tsx` *unless* you name it something other than `favicon.ico`.

#### Important!!!

Others have failed to mention this. Make sure you do not have a `favicon.ico` file in both `public/` *and* `src/app/` directory or else NextJS will not know which one to pick:

> Error: A conflicting public file and page file was found for path /favicon.ico

This error message is only visible if you inspect the page and click the `/favicon.ico` link in the `head` tag.

Answer (score 1):

in layout.tsx

```js
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  icons: {
    icon: {
      url: "/favicon.png",
      type: "image/png",
    },
    shortcut: { url: "/favicon.png", type: "image/png" },
  },
};
```

and in public I have a image called favicon.png

Answer (score 1):

Step One: Delete the favicon.ico from root(app) directory.

Step Two: Place your icon in the root(app) directory like (app/icon.svg) app/icon.png, app/icon.jpg.

Answer (score 1):

You can also do `icons: '<Path to icon>'` (instead of passing an array) i.e:

In `app/layout.tsx`:

```
export const metadata: Metadata = {
  title: ...
  ...
  icons: 'favicon.ico',
}
```

Also, make sure that the file (like `favicon.ico`) is **either** in `/app`, or in `/public` **but not in both**.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the only method that worked is here.

This example is from the [kapeesa](https://www.kapeesa.com/) gaming platform

Rename your icon file name to `favicon.ico`

e.g mine was `kapeesa.png` which I renamed to `favicon.ico`

Put your `favicon.ico` file in the `src/app/` directory.

You usually have to replace the one you find in this path `src/app/`

That's it. It'll be used, fingerprinted, kabam.

Answer (score 0):

just put your favicon.ico in the root of `src/app/` or `app/` directory
if still not working rename `favicon` to `icon`

Answer (score 0):

In the latest versions (app directory), you can simply add your favicon file in the `app/` directory, just make sure to name the icon using the expected Next standard according to your icon type, from the [doc](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/app-icons):

| File convention | Supported file types | Valid locations |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [`favicon`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/app-icons#favicon) | `.ico` | `app/` |
| [`icon`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/app-icons#icon) | `.ico`, `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.png`, `.svg` | `app/**/*` |
| [`apple-icon`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/app-icons#apple-icon) | `.jpg`, `.jpeg`, `.png` | `app/**/*` |

If your filve is an SVG icon, you can therefore simply put it in `app/icon.svg`. You don't need to edit the metadata, and you certainly don't need to convert your file to a `.ico` file.

The `<link />` entry generated is something that looks like:

```html
<link 
    rel="icon"
    href="/icon.svg?9905c4fc24cc0f60"
    type="image/svg+xml"
    sizes="any"
>
```

### Per path icon

According to this documentation, if you are using an image icon, you can even have a different icon in subpaths. For example, if you have a `dashboard` subtree in your app:

[image]

You can have a diffrent favicon displayed for your users when they are in a dahboard page, you would simply need to have these files:

- `app/icon.svg` the icon for all your pages unless its redefined in a subtree
- `app/dashboard/icon.svg` the icon used in any page in the dashboard subtree (unless of course if its redefined in a sub-subtree)

### Programmatically generate icons

You can even [use a script to generate your icon](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/metadata/app-icons#generate-icons-using-code-js-ts-tsx), in that case the name conventions are:

| File convention | Supported file types | Valid locations |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `icon` | `.js`, `.ts`, `.tsx` | `app/**/*` |
| `apple-icon` | `.js`, `.ts`, `.tsx` | `app/**/*` |

In that case, you can use the [dynamic route parameters](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes) to customize even further and have an icon that is built for a given path slug. For example, you could add the following icon in `app/dashboard/[slug]/icon.tsx` to have a black circle with the first letter of your slug drawn:

[image]

```
import { ImageResponse } from "next/og";

export const size = {
    width: 32,
    height: 32,
};
export const contentType = "image/png";

export default function Icon({ params }: { params: { slug: string } }) {
    return new ImageResponse(
        (
            <div
                style={{
                    fontSize: 24,
                    background: "black",
                    width: "100%",
                    height: "100%",
                    display: "flex",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    justifyContent: "center",
                    color: "white",
                    backgroundColor: "black",
                    borderRadius: "100%",
                    textTransform: "capitalize",
                }}
            >
                {params.slug[0]}
            </div>
        ),
        {
            ...size,
        },
    );
}
```

The `<link />` entry generated is something that looks like:

```html
<link
    rel="icon"
    href="/dashboard/cloud-computing/icon?f6e1d0bb0f362374"
    type="image/png"
    sizes="32x32"
>
```