# Nextjs 13 favicon not showing up after project set up

Tags: next.js, favicon, next.js13

it seems that, even when just setting up a new project, no Favicon shows up, and as I can see that the general structure of projects has changed entirely, I'm somewhat at a loss for what to do, none of the posts I've read online discuss the issue.

Does anyone know what's going wrong, is it just because I'm running it Localhost or is it something else?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding Favicon to NextJs 13 Beta (No pages folder)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75674866/adding-favicon-to-nextjs-13-beta-no-pages-folder)