# favicon is not working in next js 13 why?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next.js13

```js
export const metadata = {
  title: "Pradeep's Resume",
  icons: {
    icon: "/icon.png",
  },
};
```

can anyone tell me why this is not working ? I try doing .ico still not working
I remove Vercel favicon and it is still there
github-link: https://github.com/pradeep800/resume/blob/main/app/layout.tsx
URL:-https://resume.pradeepbisht.com/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Adding Favicon to NextJs 13 Beta (No pages folder)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75674866/adding-favicon-to-nextjs-13-beta-no-pages-folder)

Comment: no, it's not working i am doing same things as answer said

Comment: Just use `ctrl + shift + R`

Answer (score 4):

in `app` directory, you have `favicon.ico`. delete it. looks like `next.js` using it as the default option. then it works:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

it's probably due to the caches in .next folder , delete it and see again if it works .

you can create a npm script that clean teh cache before run the dev  in pacakge.json

```json
{   
...
,"scripts": {
        "dev": "next dev",
        "build": "next build",
        "start": "next start",
        "lint": "next lint",
        "clean": "rm .next -r && next dev"
    },
}
```